# How is this size alignment working

Tags: c++, c, struct, bit-manipulation, memory-alignment

I am not able to understand the below code with respect to the comment provided. What does this code does, and what would be the equivalent code for `8-aligned`?

```
/* segment size must be 4-aligned */
attr->options.ssize &= ~3;
```

Here, `ssize` is of `unsigned int` type.

Comment: Hmm, normally you would round *up*, not down, when ensuring alignment. Possibly you should look at the surrounding code so see why rounding down is correct (for that matter, whether rounding down is correct).

Comment: As a side note, I believe C11 will solve things like this far smoother. You would simply write `sizeof(max_align_t)` and get the maximum alignment as a number of bytes 4, 8 etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since 4 in binary is 100, any value aligned to 4-byte boundaries (i.e. a multiple of 4) will have the last two bits set to zero.

3 in binary is 11, and ~3 is the bitwise negation of those bits, i.e., ...1111100. Performing a bitwise AND with that value will keep every bit the same, except the last two which will be cleared (bit & 1 == bit, and bit & 0 == 0). This gives us a the next lower or equal value that is a multiple of 4.

To do the same operation for 8 (1000 in binary), we need to clear out the lowest three bits. We can do that with the bitwise negation of the binary 111, i.e., ~7.

Comment: +1 Did you know this just by looking at it? How can I learn to do that?

Comment: @David well, it's not the first time I see code like this, so yeah, I knew what it was as soon as I looked at it.

Answer (score 13):

All powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...) can be aligned by simple a and operation.

This gives the size rounded down:

```
size &= ~(alignment - 1);
```

or if you want to round up:

```
size = (size + alignment-1) & ~(alignment-1);
```

The "alignment-1", as long as it's a value that is a power of two, will give you "all ones" up to the bit just under the power of two. `~` inverts all the bits, so you get ones for zeros and zeros for ones.

You can check that something is a power of two by:

```
bool power_of_two = !(alignment & (alignment-1))
```

This works because, for example 4:

```
4    = 00000100
4-1  = 00000011
&      --------
0    = 00000000
```

or for 16:

```
16   = 00010000
16-1 = 00001111
&      --------
0    = 00000000
```

If we use 5 instead:

```
5    = 00000101
4-1  = 00000100
&      --------
4    = 00000100
```

So not a power of two!

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps more understandable comment would be

```
/* make segment size 4-aligned
   by zeroing two least significant bits, 
   effectively rounding down */
```

Then at least for me, immediate question pops to my mind: should it really be rounded down, when it is size? Wouldn't rounding up be more appropriate:

```
attr->options.ssize = (attr->options.ssize + 3) & ~3;
```

As already said in other answers, to make it 8-aligned, 3 bits need to be zeroed, so use `7` instead of `3`. So, we might make it into a function:

```
unsigned size_align(unsigned size, unsigned bit_count_to_zero) 
{
  unsigned bits = (1 << bit_count_to_zero) - 1;
  return (size + bits) & ~bits;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`~3` is the bit pattern `...111100`. When you do a bitwise AND with that pattern, it clears the bottom two bits, i.e. rounds down to the nearest multiple of 4.

`~7` does the same thing for 8-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The code ensures the bottom two bits of `ssize` are cleared, guaranteeing that `ssize` is a multiple of 4.  Equivalent code for 8-aligned would be

```
attr->options.ssize &= ~7;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = number & ~3
```

The **number** is rounded off to the *nearest multiple of 4* that is *lesser* than `number`
Ex:

```
      if number is 0,1,2 or 3, the `number` is rounded off to 0
```

similarly `if number is 4,5,6,or 7,`number`is rounded off to 4`

But if this is related to **memory alignment**, the memory must be aligned upwards and not downwards.